# Delete called twice in Cloud Files API

Tags: winapi, filesystems, virtualfilesystem

I am trying to implement a virtual drive using a Cloud Files API. I can not make Delete operation to work. For some reason the CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE callback is called twice.

I have build two samples in C++ and in C# using two different approaches and in both cases I have the same results:

1. CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE is called.
2. CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE is called again.
3. CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE_COMPLETION is called.

This behavior is somewhat confusing. Can anybody explain why this happening and what should I do inside the second call? Can I somehow distinguish them and ignore one of these calls?

Comment: *"Can I somehow distinguish them"* - You could store a registry of pending delete's. On `CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE` check the registry to see, if there already is an entry. If there isn't, this is the first call, so add it. If there is, this is the second (or a subsequent) call. On `CF_CALLBACK_TYPE_NOTIFY_DELETE_COMPLETION` remove the entry from the registry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced this issue in Windows File Manager, but when I did "delete" operation in Powershell there was no the problem. So this probably bug or some limitation of Windows File Manager.